# Using a .BAT file to change a USB drive-letter

Tags: windows-7, command-line, drive-letter

Is it possible to use a `.bat` file to change a USB drive letter or is there a command line to change a drive-letter and place that in a `.bat` file?
All of this is in Windows 7.

Comment: Don't use a bat, that is the old way.  The new way is Powershell.  http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2011/03/14/change-drive-letters-and-labels-via-a-simple-powershell-command.aspx

Answer (score 4):

It is possible using *diskpart*.

1. Open Command Prompt.
2. Type: "*diskpart*"
3. At the DISKPART prompt, type: "*list volume*" and make note of the number of the simple volume whose drive letter you want to assign, change, or remove.
4. At the DISKPART prompt, type: "*select volume **n***" Select the volume, where "**n**" is the volume's number, whose drive letter you want to assign, change, or remove.
5. At the DISKPART prompt, type one of the following: "*assign letter=**L***" where "*L*" is the drive letter you want to assign or change or "*remove letter=**L***" where L is the drive letter you want to remove.

If you want to use all of this in a batch file you can put your *diskpart* commands in a text file, one command per line. Then, call it from within a batch file using "*diskpart /s file.txt*". See: [DISKPART Scripting](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc766465%28WS.10%29.aspx)

Source: [Microsoft](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc757491%28v=ws.10%29.aspx#BKMK_CMD)